How to pass a callback parameter to a PermissionState
In Android Compose I am handling permissions using Accompanist permission library.
The library provides the interface PermissionState that is created by the Composable function rememberPermissionState.
How can I pass a parameter to the onPermissionResult callback function? The parameter is originated in a higher callback function (suppose a Button that when clicked triggers the permission request workflow). Hence, I can't create the PermissionState object from inside the callback, because

Composable invocations can only happen in the context of a @Composable
function

Here, my code where printSetting is the parameter
val permissionState: PermissionState = rememberPermissionState(
    permission = Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
    onPermissionResult = {}
)
fun onPrintSettingsChanged(printSetting: String) {
    if (!permissionState.status.isGranted) {
        permissionState.launchPermissionRequest()
    }
}

onPermissionResult: (Boolean) -> Unit should use printSetting, hence I need to extend it to: myFunction: (Boolean, String) -> Unit and use it like that:
onPermissionResult = { myFunction(it, printSetting) }

Note that I know I can solve this by using a variable at the level of the Composable, but the aim is to separate the permission workflow from it.

onPermissionResult already receives a parameter: a Boolean indicating whether or not the permission was granted. That is stemming from ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission more than Accompanist.

@CommonsWare sure, I edited the question hoping it's clearer now

You would need to clone ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission to support this parameter, then fork Accompanist and have it use your clone. You might be able to get away by just forking Accompanist, having it supply a Boolean-only lambda to ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission and then calling Boolean plus T lambda that you supply. In either case, you would need to  fork that portion of Accompanist.

@CommonsWare I see, thanks
